# Laravel returns error max prepared statements after getting many count()'s

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting the following error from Laravel.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1461 Can't create
>   more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)
>   (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `guild`)

I have tried removing the guild count statement, but this makes the next SQL query give an error.

```php
$users = User::count();
$crowdfunding = CrowdfundingSettings::find(1);
$guilds = Guild::count();
$data = [
    'totalItems' => ItemTemplate::totalCustomItems(),
    'totalAbilities' => Ability::totalCustom(),
    'totalMobs' => MobTemplate::all()->count(),
    'totalQuests' => Quest::all()->count(),
    'totalLootTables' => LootTable::all()->count(),
    'totalMerchantTables' => MerchantTable::all()->count(),
    'totalDialogue' => Dialogue::all()->count(),
    'totalCraftingRecipes' => CraftingRecipe::all()->count(),
    'totalItemSets' => ItemSetProfile::all()->count(),
    'totalSkills' => Skill::totalCustom()
];

return response()->json([
    'crowdfunding_settings' => $crowdfunding,
    'accounts' => $users,
    //'guilds' => $guilds,
    'data' => $data,
]);
```

I am expecting results to from the statement, yet I get an error. I have increased max prepared statements to 32k, but I still get this error displaying it is set to 16k.

Comment: Just drop `all()->`. If it's a lot of data, it needs to be loaded in memory. As you only want to count, loading all data in memory isn't necessary.

Comment: @Dimitri - please add as an answer rather than a comment - it will help if it can close out the question if it is the right answer. (Which it might be - makes a lot of sense to me.)

Comment: @Watercayman yes I know but honestly I didn't have the time. Make PtrTon's answer as correct. I'm cool with it. Good luck with your project. Remember that eloquent translates to sql in the exact order as written. If by change you get a result you didn't expect, reordering the eloquent sequence often fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dimitri mentioned (and also confirmed [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-how-to-get-the-row-count?page=0#reply=10231)) you should not use `->all()` when you only need the count and not the data in the model itself.

Replace `$data` like so:

```
    $data = [
        'totalItems' => ItemTemplate::totalCustomItems(),
        'totalAbilities' => Ability::totalCustom(),
        'totalMobs' => MobTemplate::count(),
        'totalQuests' => Quest::count(),
        'totalLootTables' => LootTable::count(),
        'totalMerchantTables' => MerchantTable::count(),
        'totalDialogue' => Dialogue::count(),
        'totalCraftingRecipes' => CraftingRecipe::count(),
        'totalItemSets' => ItemSetProfile::count(),
        'totalSkills' => Skill::totalCustom()
    ];
```

Counting the amount of mob templates using `MobTemplate::all()->count()` will result in the following sql `SELECT * FROM mob_template;`. The results of that will be loaded into a Eloquent collection, that collection will then count the items it contains in PHP. This is very slow, memory heavy and as it turns out you might also run into issues with prepared statements.

Count the amount of mob templates using `MobTemplate::count()` will result in the following sql `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mob_template;`. This means the database does all the heavy lifting for counting the records and it only returns the result. That way eloquent does not have to load a collection with a bunch of data and it does not have to count all its items in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're disposing PreparedQuery or any other prepared SQL Command after execution. Disposing calls ClosePreparedStatement.